# Checking mail and running a script without downloading

Tags: scripting, email, fetchmail

I'm writing a script to run certain processing activities (mainly moving some data files to another machine where they can backed up), but I only know when to trigger the copy when a mail is delivered to a specific folder in an IMAP mailserver (which is outside my network).

So I'm looking for something that can *only* perform a mail check and *in case of new mail* trigger the script. I do not want to download the contents of the IMAP folder unless there is no other choice.

Can `fetchmail`, `getmail` or `offlineimap` do this, or is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check imapfilter, which this you can check remote imap server - https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter